# Simple and proper methods in Isar

Tags: isabelle, reference-request, isar

https://isabelle.systems/cookbook/src/proofs/methods/Chained_Facts.thy

talks about

> We note a slight difference. In the variant with intro, a trivial goal remains
> that we need to solve by ‹assumption›. The reason is that ‹intro› is a ∗‹simple method› in Isabelle jargon, while ‹rule› is ∗‹proper›. Simple methods ignore chained facts and insert them into the goal state, while proper methods will usually act on them in some way.

Is there anything more to know about *simple* and *proper* methods? Especially, where can I find a list of the methods belonging to these categories?

Comment: Is this a reference request? If not, feel free to remove the tag and/or elaborate!

Comment: I didn't know about that tag but yes, it is!